# google-api-client in Rails: Caught error not in gzip format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-client

When using the google-api-client in plain ruby file, it works fine.

But as soon as I use it from Rails app, I get this error `Caught error not in gzip format`.

**The debug log looks like this:**

```
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.149932 #17520] DEBUG -- : Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?fields=nextPageToken%2C%20items%28%2A%29&q=%27root%27%20in%20parents&spaces=drive
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.202377 #17520] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Sending: POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.202739 #17520] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Data: grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJleGNlbGlmeS1hcHBAZXhjZWxpZnktaW8uaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9vYXV0aDIvdjMvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE1MjI2NjE1NjcsImlhdCI6MTUyMjY2MTQ0Nywic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL2RyaXZlIn0.iMyXxO49bxBl-xRxsDF3Hmj7Wkl2lIfuOf4yrNq7UABPnzEriAjdD92X6qTbmGXClOOdAHhbxySQ2ZO6nxVOsTucuF2-WOyQHZcNZxWgnZ5i62qfaUR3M8rzUn4jwWEjbyTGvDiV0NoyEXFja1iSoPdbjE8EU_ONg1G9R7qzJNkMl0Wpg7RxTepWBNfZv9cNysXpVwtFxqez3YmGdGl93kzWTbbaBs0xuhvom_Yu1uBO_lX2Un0Vlih69d5f3WcsunDkQf3Z_jtHv0ZK-2aOvxnLIimMummMyyrn1sBIouc7FNsZKOSLMqTUsL9WJyHetOJZKsY4er9yXY33xzRI_A
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.203579 #17520] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: www.googleapis.com:443
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.815840 #17520] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Status: 200
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.816152 #17520] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Benchmark: 0.612795 seconds
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.816671 #17520] DEBUG -- : Caught error not in gzip format
D, [2018-04-02T12:31:47.817137 #17520] DEBUG -- : Error - #<Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format, input="{\n \"access_token\": \"ya29.c.ElmRBS-MRbG48N2boi6f-S6b54eXd7Tv-29_Wa1VBUsz4f4XfnLjd3rYDlciKuzmieU7fGAUDTypOFXF2K_z_Wulw7OtGRiCu1iHU-chn-9TqdQkXZytrW5AUA\",\n \"token_type\": \"Bearer\",\n \"expires_in\": 3600\n}\n">
```

**My Gemfile is like this:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'httparty'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'rack', github: 'rack/rack'
gem 'rack-protection', github: 'sinatra/sinatra'
gem 'sidekiq'

gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'axlsx', :git => 'https://github.com/marisveide/axlsx.git'
gem 'roo', '~>2.7.1'
gem 'roo-xls'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'translit'

gem 'vuejs-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'lodash-rails'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.12.5'
gem 'browser'
gem 'addressable'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'shopify_app', '~> 7.2.10'
gem 'shopify_api', '~> 4.9.0'
gem 'omniauth-shopify-oauth2', '~> 1.1.17'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rack-tracker'
gem 'filesize'
gem 'slack-notifier'
gem 'spawnling', '~> 2.1' # Process spawner
gem 'crono'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'faraday', '0.9.1'
gem 'google-api-client'

gem 'affiliate', path: 'engines/affiliate'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', ">= 2.0.0.beta"
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'diffy'
  gem 'vcr' # Records real HTTP responses from web, and then stubs them
  gem 'httplog'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'debugger-ruby_core_source'
  gem 'derailed'
  gem 'rerun'
end
```

The code I am running is basically this:

```
require 'httplog'
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'
require 'signet/oauth_2/client'

ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "../config/google-api-service-account.json"

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2
drive = Drive::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default([Google::Apis::DriveV2::AUTH_DRIVE])

files = drive.list_files
files.items.each do |file|
  puts "#{file.title} [#{file.kind}] [#{file.mime_type}]"
end
```

This plain ruby file works fine, but as soon as I run it from Rails app with that Gemfile, it has that error.

I tried to pin the faraday version to 0.9.1 (uninstalled the 0.9.2 version), but that still doesn't solve the issue. (ref to this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/367)

I understand that this might be due to some other gem, because it works with plain ruby script, but cannot find what might be causing this issue.

Please, help - how to make Google API work in Ruby app?

Thanks!

Maris